# Not able to change default group for user with `sudo usermod -g`

Tags: user-mode-linux

I have looked at the questions and answer here at U&L but I still cannot get my default group to change from a user.

```
[red@ws-red-l ~]$ whoami
red
[red@ws-red-l ~]$ groups
yellow green
[red@ws-red-l ~]$ sudo usermod -g green red
usermod: no changes
[red@ws-red-l ~]$ sudo usermod -G green red
[red@ws-red-l ~]$ groups
yellow green
[red@ws-red-l ~]$ touch file
[red@ws-red-l ~]$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 red yellow 0 Feb 18 13:51 file
```

I would prefer if `red` did not belong to group `yellow` so when I do a `touch file` the group of the file would be `green`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There are some caveats to using usermod according to its manual:      You must make certain that the named user is not executing any processes when this command is being executed if the user´s numerical user ID, the user´s name, or the user´s home directory is being changed.  usermod checks this on Linux, but only check if the user is logged in according to utmp on other architectures.

Comment: You have to log out and log in again.

Comment: Or log in on another terminal to check if all still works **before** you log out in your old one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works just as you ran it:

```
sudo usermod -g green red
```

You just need to log in as `red` again for the new groups settings to be read. You can check with:

```
red@oregano ~ $ whoami
red
red@oregano ~ $ groups 
red
red@oregano ~ $ sudo usermod -g users red
red@oregano ~ $ groups 
red
red@oregano ~ $ su red
Password: 
red@oregano ~ $ groups 
users
```